# neuralnet in caret: wrong model type for classification

Tags: r

I'm trying to train a model to predict a continuous numeric variable with the "neuralnet" method in the Caret package. When the below line of code is executed, the following error is thrown:

> Error in train.default(Cadence_IVs, Cadence_Train_Response, method =
>   "neuralnet",  :    wrong model type for classification

```
NN_Cadence <- train(Cadence_IVs, Cadence_Train_Response, method = "neuralnet", layer1 = 10, layer2 = 5, decay = 0.1, linear.output = TRUE)
```

This is what the data looks likes, there are 105,000 rows:

```
RiderID     Index      Date      Time  Average_Gradient  Max_Gradient   Distance   Highest_point  Speed         Power      Cadence
1           27330   3/28/2011  8:19:36       0              6.2          5132.29     12.8          47.9653271    63.3        71.5 
15           991    1/29/2016  6:05:04     -1.5              0            242.9       52.3         10.5608695    267.2       72.6 
15           979    1/29/2016  6:51:19       0               0           581.97      -23           10.03396552   239.2       77.6 
12          49047   4/14/2013  7:45:52       0              3.5           471.2       45.4         18.848        383.6       140.4 
11          46677   5/30/2015  15:25:44    -7.8            -2.6           410.7       124.4        18.66818182   98.3        97.9
```

"RiderID" is coded as a Factor, and "Date" is coded as a Date variable. Time is coded as a Character but is excluded from Cadence_IVs. All the other variables are coded as "Numeric" data types, including the Response Variable which is "Cadence."

Cadence_IVs is a matrix of all the columns except for Cadence and Time. Cadence_Train_Response is a one column matrix of the values of Cadence.

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if I missed any details that might be helpful.

Comment: In the current state this is not reproducible. Please `dput()` the minimal amount of sample data for both objects needed to reproduce the error. I tried to reproduce it with what you have here, but there aren't enough rows and since you didn't `dput()` the classes and metadata is missing. If you feel the `dput()` would be too long then try to reproduce your error with builtin datasets.

Comment: Having said that, this error is what you get when you have a factor dependent variable. I know you said it's not a factor, but make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Neural net from caret only deals with regression and takes 3 params i.e. layers 1-3.

You have to feed those parameters in the tune grid. This in an illustration, hope you get the point.

```
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.layer1=4:6, .layer2=2, .layer3=0)
train(mpg ~ cyl + vs + am + carb, data = mtcars, method="neuralnet", tuneGrid = tunegrid)
```